# AWS EC2 Mautic Install won't even start

Tags: amazon-ec2, mautic

I have a fresh EC2 setup on AWS and have loaded Mautic files into the main /html directory. When I go to that directory, I just get a screen saying:

"The site is currently offline due to encountering an error. If the problem persists, please contact the system administrator."

I have been digging everywhere to find a solution. I know this is not a real error message and it gives no details. The error logs are not being helpful either. There is one thing that shows over and over in error_log which is:

AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'

I have rebooted this server, tried different combos of ownership and permissions, etc. I'm at a loss. I'm hoping someone can provide some insight to get me over this hump and actually get Mautic installed.

SIDE NOTE: Please do not suggest using Bitnami to install Mautic. We've already done that and found it to be very unstable. We are hoping a clean install that isn't dependant on anything else will work better for us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

run following commands:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/mautic/

sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/mautic/
```